# How to make an Xcode playground rotate to landscape

Tags: swift, swift-playground, screen-rotation

I am trying to test a landscape view, but so far I cannot make progress. My code looks like this:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {

  override func loadView() {

    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Hallo"
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(label)
    self.view = view
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 20),
                                 label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)])
    simulateDeviceRotation(toOrientation: .landscapeLeft)
 }

  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    //simulateDeviceRotation(toOrientation: .landscapeLeft)

  }
}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
func simulateDeviceRotation(toOrientation orientation: UIDeviceOrientation) {
  let orientationValue = NSNumber(value: orientation.rawValue)
  UIDevice.current.setValue(orientationValue, forKey: "orientation")
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

When I uncomment the call to `simulateDeviceRotation(toOrientation:)` in `loadView()`, the result is:

[Rotation in loadView()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1F7Y.png)

And, when I uncomment `simulateDeviceRotation(toOrientation:)` in `viewDidAppear(_:)`, the result is:

[rotation in viewDidAppear(_:)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43dSw.png)

Of course, I would like to see the second result, but with the horizontal rotation of the first. Can you please point me in the right direction? I am missing something but I have not been able to finde it.

Answer (score 4):

Don't mess with orientation, you won't succeed.

Change the last line of your code to:

```
var myViewController = MyViewController()
myViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 668, height: 375)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = myViewController
```

and remove everything that handles with device orientation in `loadView`, `viewDidAppear` and remove method `simulateDeviceRotation`.

## Update

If you set an arbitrary value as `preferredContentSize`, you will get into problems with constraints or worse like the view is displaced in the live view.

What I did: first read the default values of current content size:

```
print(myViewController.preferredContentSize)
```

This was 375.0 as width and 668.0 as height for me.

So just swap this values for the new `preferredContentSize` and everything should be fine.